# How to split a string on whitespace and on special char while getting there offset values in java

Tags: java, regex, string, split, compilation

I am try to split/match a string on Punctuation and white space and also need to get there offset values.

Ex  - "I live, in India."

i want output like - ["I","live", ",", "in", "India", "."]
and also the start and end index value of each token.

I have tried using -

String text = "I live, in India.";

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\S+");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}");         
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(text);
Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(text);
```

This will give the desire result but can i combine both the pattern in a single pattern ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [`Matcher#start`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start())

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\S+\\b|\\p{Punct}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("I live, in India.");
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group() + " => " + matcher.start());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
I => 0
live => 2
, => 6
in => 8
India => 11
. => 16
```

**Explanation of regex:**

1. `\b` specifies [word boundary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html).
2. `|` specifies `OR`.
3. `\p{Punct}` specifies [punctuation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).
4. `\S+` specifies [one or more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) non-whitespace character.

Comment: `\S` also matches what `\p{Punct}` matches, so you risk grabbing too much, although these cases are likely to be rare.

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew for the valuable feedback.